# Terraform Fargate ECS giving invalid or unknown key: requires_compatibilities

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I ran Terraform plan on a Terraform script to enable Fargate but I get the following error:

> Error: aws_ecs_task_definition.task: : invalid or unknown key:
>   requires_compatibilities

and

> Error: aws_ecs_service.service: : invalid or unknown key: launch_type

Not sure why Terraform is not accepting the keys `launch_type` and `requires_compatibilities` for enabling Fargate.

Below is my task and ECS service setup for Terraform:

### Terraform

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                   = "${var.name_prefix}_gateway"
  container_definitions    = "${template_file.task.rendered}"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "bridge"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name                               = "${var.name_prefix}_service"
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  cluster                            = "${aws_ecs_cluster.terraform_cluster.id}"
  task_definition                    = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.task.arn}"
  desired_count                      = "${var.desired_count}"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
  iam_role                           = "${var.ecs_service_role}"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.svc.arn}"
    container_name   = "task"
    container_port   = 8000
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Terraform and the AWS provider are you using?

Comment: Terraform v0.11.7
+ provider.aws v0.1.4
+ provider.template v0.1.1

Comment: Not the answer to your question, yet relevant, you can't use a `bridge` network with Fargate; `awsvpc` only.

Answer (score 1):

`requires_compatibilities` and `launch_type` were introduced in [`v1.6.0` of the AWS provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#160-december-18-2017).

Update your provider to `1.6.0` or higher and you should be fine.

Note that `v0.1.4` came out in August 2017, followed by the `v1.0.0` release on September 27, 2017 which was long before the Fargate announcement.

Comment: I thought I was running the latest version, was wrong. Upgrading aws.provider to latest version resolved the issue , as mentioned above. Thanks.